# How to execute php script using drush?

Tags: drush

I am new to Drush. How can I execute this script to remove comments of a specific user?

```
$uid = xx // the spam users id;
$query = db_query("SELECT cid FROM {comments} WHERE uid = %d", $uid);
while($cid = db_result($query)) {
  comment_delete($cid);
}
```

Also, that would be great if you could tell me how to complete the script so that it takes username instead of $uid.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can convert the script in a [Drush shell script](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/php-script/).

> A drush shell script is any Unix shell script file that has its "execute" bit set (i.e., via `chmod +x myscript.drush`) and that begins with a specific line:
>
> ```
>     #!/usr/bin/env drush
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>     #!/full/path/to/drush
> ```

Drush scripts are better than Bash scripts for the following reasons:

- They are written in PHP
- Drush can bootstrap the site before running the script

The following is the example you can find on [helloword.script](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/helloworld.script).

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush

//
// This example demonstrates how to write a drush
// "shebang" script.  These scripts start with the
// line "#!/usr/bin/env drush" or "#!/full/path/to/drush".
//
// See `drush topic docs-scripts` for more information.
//
drush_print("Hello world!");
drush_print();
drush_print("The arguments to this command were:");

//
// If called with --everything, use drush_get_arguments
// to print the commandline arguments.  Note that this
// call will include 'php-script' (the drush command)
// and the path to this script.
//
if (drush_get_option('everything')) {
  drush_print("  " . implode("\n  ", drush_get_arguments()));
}
//
// If --everything is not included, then use
// drush_shift to pull off the arguments one at
// a time.  drush_shift only returns the user
// commandline arguments, and does not include
// the drush command or the path to this script.
//
else {
  while ($arg = drush_shift()) {
    drush_print('  ' . $arg);
  }
}

drush_print();
```

You can made the script executable, so you can  execute it with `<script file> <parameters>` where `<script name>` is the script name, and `<parameters>` are the parameters passed to the script; if the script is not executable, you call it with `drush <script name> <parameters>`.

Comment: Are PHP tags not needed?

Comment: As far as I recall, you don't use PHP tags in Drush scripts.

Answer (score 30):

With [`drush php-eval`](http://drushcommands.com/drush-6x/core/php-eval), you can run your script *without* having to save it to a file first:

```
drush php-eval '
  $uid = 1234; 
  $query = db_query("SELECT cid FROM {comments} WHERE uid = %d", $uid);
  while($cid = db_result($query)) {
    comment_delete($cid);
  }
'
```

This uses nested quotation marks, so to prevent a mess I recommend to use only double quotes `"` within the PHP code.

Answer (score 16):

I think you're looking at `drush -d scr --uri=example.org sample_script.php` to execute  sample_script.php.

Answer (score 11):

We can use `drush php-script script_name` to excute php file in Drush.

For help related to Drush for executing php files Type `Drush php-script --help` will list you the commands

Note: I have placed php scirpt in root folder of Drupal

Answer (score 6):

It is simple you can run a php script by `drush scr ~/sample.php`.

Answer (score 4):

On your command line, from anywhere, run:

```
$ drush --root=/path/to/drupal-installation --uri=youdomain.com scr /path/to/your/script.php
```

In case you are already at /path/to/drupal-installation just run:

```
$ drush --uri=youdomain.com scr /path/to/your/script.php
```

In case you are even further ahead at /path/to/drupal-installation/sites/youdomain.com than just run:

```
$ drush scr /path/to/your/script.php
```

your script.php file:

```
<?php
// Not always needed but sometimes you might have to first login as an administrator.
$admin_uid = 1;
$form_state = array('uid' => $admin_uid);
user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);

// Now the logged in user global $user object become available.
global $user;
print_r($user);

// Do whatever you want here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `db_result` has been removed in Drupal 7. The above code can be changed to:

```
$result = db_query($query);
foreach($result as $cid) {
  comment_delete($cid);
}
```

If you want to use username instead of the uid then you can get the username using this:

```
$username = user_load($uid)->name;
```