# How do I find the user ID  knowing the username, when using drush?

Tags: drush

That would be much more handy to use Drush rather than executing a SQL query to find a user ID. So I am wondering what drush command can be used that takes a username, and returns the equivalent user ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [user-information](http://drush.ws/#user-information).

Comment: Great. Do you know how this 'drush user-information' command can be integrated into this script which deletes all the posts by the user http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/how-to-execute-php-script-using-drush