# One time db scrub with .install file

Tags: 7, database, installation

I need to scrub a production db to replace paths in the body field. Being a production database, it needs to happen in a time-sensitive, well-documented way with the solution frozen in code. I'd assume that a .install file would be the best way to do this.

What would a one time install script look like to search the database for "http://mysite.com" and replace with "https://www.mysite.com" in the default body field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically do things like this outside of modules, and instead use a [drush script](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/how-to-execute-php-script-using-drush).

The script itself, would go something like

- Go into maintenance mode
- Do an [EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708) to get my nids.
- Loop through each nid, and
- Load the node, and make an [entity metadata wrapper](https://drupal.org/node/1021556)
- Do the search and replace on the fields
- Save the node
- Exit maintenance mode

Before and after running the script, I usually do a `drush sql-dump`.  You can even combine all of this into a single script

```
#!/bin/bash

drush variable-set -y --always-set maintenance_mode 1
drush sql-dump --result-file=~/db/before.sql
drush scr path/to/my/script.php
drush sql-dump --result-file=~/db/after.sql
drush variable-delete -y --exact maintenance_mode
```

By doing a drush script, you can really ensure that the task runs when you want it to, and you aren't bound by execution time limits.  I also find it easier to debug.

That said, you should just be able to use [Pathologic](https://drupal.org/project/pathologic) to rewrite the URLs.  Install/enable it, and add it to your text formats, and configure to do the path fixups.

Comment: excellent. Already using pathologic to filter on input for all content going forward, just need to scrub old content.