# How can I run PHP code without writing a module?

Tags: 7

I need to attach a field to some bundles. A PHP snippet will do the job for me, so I don't need a module.The below snippet is what must be executed :

```
$field_name = 'field_custom_image';
// Create the field.
$field = array(
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'type' => 'image',
);
field_create_field($field);
```

and then the snippet to add this field to bundle :

```
// Create the instance.
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'bundle' => 'article',
  'label' => 'Image',
  'description' => 'An image for the article.',
  'required' => TRUE,
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

Is there a way to run PHP code directly in Drupal, without the need to write a module, install it, make it run, and uninstall it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for both working answers and good editions made to my question. I voted all answers up as solutions to my problem,now it is a hard decision for me to select one of those answers as the best solution cause all works.

Comment: If you were to show the code you need to run, the answers would be more complete.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for advice, I will attach the PHP snippet to my question.

Comment: Closely related question & answers: [How to execute php script using drush](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/9837)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're saying "I need to run some PHP" and "I don't need a module" in the same thought, I'd suggest that you're going down the wrong path, either in the approach to this specific problem, or the approach to building the site in general.

`drush scr` will help you if that's the direction that you really want to go, or you could write a standalone PHP script (basically just copy/paste everything through the `drupal_bootstrap()` call from index.php, and add your custom code after) but there are a couple other things you could look at:

- Export your content type (and it's field bases and instances) with the Features module. IMO, you should be doing this anyway.
- Create a simple "site modifications" module, and include things like this in update hooks. Note that if you want to do this, you should create an empty module (with no update hooks), enable it on your site, and then add your update hook to get Drupal to see the update.

Many sites that I've worked on have had a combination of both of those solutions. Config should mostly go into exported Features modules, and anything that can't (are you *really sure* it can't?) can go into an update hook.

Comment: Thanks for advises , specially for informing about the use of update hooks . very usefull

Comment: Could you please mention some problems which may be caused by running PHP codes this approach? I mean attaching fields to some content types just by running PHP scrips?

Comment: Alternative to drupal 7:  ```drush php-script {path_to_file.php}```

https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/php-script/

Answer (score 21):

Yes, there is, but given your description I wonder if it will help you:

1. Install module [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)
2. Go to http://yoursite/devel/php
3. Enter your code and execute it.

Comment: The Devel module also comes with an "Execute PHP" block, that you can place in a region.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to run code just once, you can do it without installing any module, including the Devel module.

Write a PHP file (e.g. *tasks.php*), put it where the cron.php file that comes with Drupal is, and add the following code.

```
/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
drupal_set_time_limit(240);

// Your code here.
```

If you are already using Drush for maintaining/deploying your site, then you could make a [Drush script](http://www.drush.org/en/master/shellscripts/#drush-shell-scripts). In this way, it could be executed by CLI, and it could receive any arguments, making it re-usable for many occasions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush

// Your code here.
// Access the options with drush_get_option(), or any argument with drush_shift().
```

You could also execute a PHP script with [`drush php-eval`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/php-eval/) (or just `drush ev`), for example:

```
drush php-eval 'print time();'
```

I would create a Drush script, but if you cannot install Drush, or you need to execute PHP code from the browser, the first method works fine.

Answer (score 12):

Add your code snippet to a file and save the file as `file_name.php` in your Drupal site root folder. Then run the following command in a terminal, from within the Drupal site root folder as your working directory:

`drush scr file_name.php`

This command will execute your PHP file. (To get an idea of the execution, you may include some print statements in your file, which will output the text, variable values etc. to the terminal where you execute the drush command.)

**Note:** As a prerequisite, you need to have [`drush`](http://www.drush.org/) installed on your system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Php` inline of [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) but
lets get you one of my tricks in drupal to running my custom code without any module.

first create a `menu item` in `hook_menu`

```
function yourmdoule_menu()
{

    $items['ytest'] = array(
        'title' => 'my debug and devel test tool ',
        'description' => 'create for debug and faster develop',
        'page callback' => 'my_function',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' => true,
    );
    return $items;
}

function my_function{

/// run every want you want
}
```

then clear the cache ( because menu items cached in drupal ), and put everything you want in `my_function` and just type `yoursite.com/ytest`

I hope it will help you in projects "dada" ;)

Answer (score 2):

The goal of Drupal modules is to provide separate logic to certain components, so they can be disabled if something goes wrong.

#### [`hook_install`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7.x)/[`hook_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x)

In your case which is creating a new field on one-time basis, the ideal scenario is to use either [`hook_install`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7.x) or [`hook_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x).

If you don't have a custom module (btw. you can also use exported feature module for that), create a new one just for updates (e.g. `site_updates`). In Drupal 7, all you need is to create folder with 3 files: `.info`, `.module` and `.install` and define install or update hook in your `.install`. Using install/update hook is convenient in order to have consistent environments, especially when you've multiple Drupal servers (such as dev, test and prod), so the change can be invoked during the next deployment.

If you still don't want to create module, here are other methods.

#### One-time execution

If you need only to execute certain PHP code only one time, you can:

- Activate *Devel* module and paste the code at `/devel/php`,
- Use [`drush`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) (and its `eval`/`ev` command) to execute PHP code, e.g.

  ```
  drush ev 'field_create_field(["field_name"=>"foo", "type"=>"image"]);'
  drush ev 'print_r(field_info_field("foo"));'
  ```
- Use `drush scr` to execute PHP script:

  ```
  drush scr my_file.php
  ```

  where `my_file.php` is your plain PHP script with your code to execute.

#### Specific page execution

To execute custom code on certain pages or components:

- Take advantage of `template.php` file in your *custom* theme (e.g. [`template_preprocess_node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7), [`template_preprocess_block`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7), [`template_preprocess_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)).
- You can use *PHP* module which provides *filter*, so you can write PHP code inside nodes, blocks, views, etc.

#### All page execution

To add and run PHP code on every page without writing a module, you can:

- Use a `settings.php` file for that. It is only recommended for simple code such as configuration override. Otherwise you should use [`hook_init`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7.x) for that as part of your custom module.
- Activate *PHP text filter*, then create a block with custom PHP code in it and place the block into footer region.